# automapper gregorian datetime to persian datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

Why I can not use the following example?

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SiteSetting, dto_site_setting>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.LastUpdate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
             src.LastUpdate.Value.ToShamsiDate()));
    }
}
```

---

```
public static class XDate
{
    public static string ToShamsiDate(this DateTime _date, char separator = '-')
    {
        var year = pcal.GetYear(_date);
        var month = pcal.GetMonth(_date).ToString("00");
        var day = pcal.GetDayOfMonth(_date).ToString("00");

        if (separator == '-')
           return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", year, month, day);
        else
           return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", year, month, day);
    }
}
```

---

I See Error:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
> optional arguments

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, your mapping code is not allowed to contain a method call that uses optional arguments. But your `ToShamsiDate()` method has an optional parameter (the `char separator = '-'`), and you are in fact calling the method from your mapping code using an optional argument (by not passing anything explicitly).

Change the method signature to make the optional parameter a required one -

```
public static string ToShamsiDate(this DateTime _date, char separator)
```

and in your mapping code pass the the argument explicitly -

```
CreateMap<SiteSetting, dto_site_setting>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.LastUpdate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
     src.LastUpdate.Value.ToShamsiDate('-')));
```